# Add a line at z=0 to ggplot2 heatmap

Tags: ggplot2, heatmap

I have plotted a heatmap in ggplot2. I want to add a curved line to the plot to show where z=0 (i.e. where the value of the data used for the fill is zero), how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example with what you tried and a more precise description of what you mean with a curved line? Are we talking anyway about a 2-D plot still?

Answer (score 1):

Since no example data or code is provided, I'll illustrate with the `volcano` dataset, representing heights of a volcano in a matrix. Since the data doesn't contain a zero point, we'll draw the line at the arbitrarily chosen 125 mark.

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Convert matrix to data.frame
df <- data.frame(
  row = as.vector(row(volcano)),
  col = as.vector(col(volcano)),
  value = as.vector(volcano)
)

# Set contour breaks at desired level
ggplot(df, aes(col, row, fill = value)) +
  geom_raster() +
  geom_contour(aes(z = value), 
               breaks = 125, col = 'red')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

If this isn't a good approximation of your problem, I'd suggest to include example data and code in your question.